# Character Animation Library

Tags: c++, animation

I am looking for character animation library which can be included in my game engine.

I prefer FOSS but, paid is good if it's price is reasonable.

So, far what Ive found is [Cal3d](https://mp3butcher.github.io/Cal3D/).

Can anyone tell, what are the other options?

I am also interested in Havok Animation which comes in the free bundle of Havok. Any thoughts about this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Animadead](http://animadead.sourceforge.net/), but that's about as dead as [Cal3d](http://gna.org/projects/cal3d/).  [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) is also a possibility if you design your models using some sort of modeling software.  There may be better options out there though...  [This gamedev post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/497472-proposing-an-open-source-dynamic-physically-simulated-character-animation-library/) may be helpful.

Comment: [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) looks pretty cool to me. But, I dont get the argument of "using some sort of modeling software". Assimp is able to work with various files. Am i missing something, cause, i find it a complete solution.

Comment: Thinking back on it, I'm not sure what I was getting at either.  Perhaps, it was just that Assimp's primary focus seems to be model importing rather than character animation, although it clearly does address animation.

Comment: Yeh, but do you know any engine using Assimp as their animation library?

Answer (score 1):

- [Alienmotion](http://www.chemical-games.com/?page_id=1057) . It looks cool. But requires maturation.
- [HALCA (Hardware Accelerated Library for Character Animation)](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~bspanlang/animation/avatarslib/doc/) This one also looks pretty interesting.

Ive also noticed I can use [ogre animation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_75.html#SEC344) code. Though, I wonder how easy/hard its gonna be. But, its also another possibility.